# Openmpi 4.0.5 fails to distribute tasks to more than 1 node

Tags: mpi, slurm, openmpi

We are having trouble with openmpi 4.0.5 on our cluster: It works as long as only 1 node is requested, but as soon as more than 1 is requested (e.g. mpirun -np 24 ./hello_world with --ntasks-per-node=12) it crashes and we get the following error message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 2
slots that were requested by the application:

  ./hello_world

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots
available for use.

A "slot" is the Open MPI term for an allocatable unit where we can
launch a process.  The number of slots available are defined by the
environment in which Open MPI processes are run:

  1. Hostfile, via "slots=N" clauses (N defaults to number of
     processor cores if not provided)
  2. The --host command line parameter, via a ":N" suffix on the
     hostname (N defaults to 1 if not provided)
  3. Resource manager (e.g., SLURM, PBS/Torque, LSF, etc.)
  4. If none of a hostfile, the --host command line parameter, or an
     RM is present, Open MPI defaults to the number of processor cores

In all the above cases, if you want Open MPI to default to the number
of hardware threads instead of the number of processor cores, use the
--use-hwthread-cpus option.

Alternatively, you can use the --oversubscribe option to ignore the
number of available slots when deciding the number of processes to
launch.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried using --oversubscribe, but this will still only use 1 node, even though smaller jobs would run that way. I have also tried specifically requesting nodes (e.g. -host node36,node37), but this results in the following error message:

```
[node37:16739] *** Process received signal ***
[node37:16739] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[node37:16739] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[node37:16739] Failing at address: (nil)
[node37:16739] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf5f0)[0x2ac57d70e5f0]
[node37:16739] [ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x13ed5a)[0x2ac57da59d5a]
[node37:16739] [ 2] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so.12(orte_daemon+0x10d7)[0x2ac57c6c4827]
[node37:16739] [ 3] orted[0x4007a7]
[node37:16739] [ 4] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x2ac57d93d505]
[node37:16739] [ 5] orted[0x400810]
[node37:16739] *** End of error message ***
```

The cluster has 59 nodes. Slurm 19.05.0 is used as a scheduler and gcc 9.1.0 to compile.

I don't have much experience with mpi - any help would be much appreciated! Maybe someone is familiar with this error and could point me towards what the problem might be.

Thanks for your help,
Johanna

Comment: `-np ...` requests a number of MPI tasks, not nodes.
Are you invoking `mpirun` within a job script submitted via `sbatch`? if so, make sure you request SLURM the right number of tasks (and nodes if needed)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I am invoking mpirun within a job script - the problem originated when porting a climate model to the machine, but I have now turned to attempting to get a simple hello world mpi program to run first. I am using #SBATCH -N 2 but the above mentioned errors happen as soon as I request more than 1 MPI task (sorry about the confusion with nodes!). Could there be a problem with the SLURM setup? @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: Try adding `#SBATCH -n 24` in your script, and then simply `mpirun ./hello_world`. Note you can also `mpirun hostname` to easily figure out how many MPI tasks were started.